# How to print the HTML message with its tags?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I would like to print a message with HTML tags. To be more accurate, this is what I want the user to see exactly:

> `<script>alert("hello world");</script>`

which means I want to include the two script tags as well.

Comment: Use `pre` tag and HTML entities.

Comment: view source here and copy!

Answer (score 1):

```
&lt;script&gt;alert("hello world");&lt;/script&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just escape the characters like :

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;hello world&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;
```

http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html